# useState and initial value as array does not work

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state

I'm trying to use react hooks in my project and I have a problem with useState when I use array as value.

As you can see in my code below, when I display `zoneItems` that it should be like `items` array I get an empty array all the time. Would you have an explanation why?

When I use an object instead of array it works

```
const ShippingCostZone = ({ zone, datas, selectedProducts, getProductById }) => {
    const items = datas.items.filter(item => item.zoneId === zone.id)
    console.log('========> items', items) // ---- SHOW the good values
    const [zoneItems, updateItems] = useState(items)
    console.log('========> zoneItems  ', zoneItems)   // ---- SHOW all the time []
.........
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you ensure that all the items are not of the zone that you are using to test the functionality? Also the last console.log shows all values or just empty array []?

Answer (score 4):

Due to async nature of hooks, you assignment `useState(items)` could be executed after you read the content of `zoneItems`. But react provides an hook that will be fired every time component will be loaded, or as you prefer, every time `zoneItems` changes his value: I'm talking about `useEffect` hook.

So if you want to print the `zoneItems` content every time is updated, just write something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    console.log(zoneItems);
}, [zoneItems])
```

This is the way that react provides to manage async assignment of state.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should initialize the state first as an array first then update it, as follows:

```
const ShippingCostZone = ({ zone, datas, selectedProducts, getProductById }) => {
    const items = datas.items.filter(item => item.zoneId === zone.id)
    console.log('========> items', items)

    const [zoneItems, updateItems] = useState([])
    
    updateitems(items)

    console.log('========> zoneItems  ', zoneItems)
```

Comment: Doing that I got this error Too many re-renders. React limits the number of renders to prevent an infinite loop.

Comment: Mmm, I think that this solution is absolutely equal to the OP code. So, it doesn't work!